# Assigning a random number to individual array elements that meet a certain criteria

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, random

I need to find all the elements in an array that are >0 and then replace each one with a random number between 0 and 5 in Python 3.

I have made an array (called L) of 20 elements that each equal 0 or 1, but am struggling to replace elements individually. (However in future this may equal a range of numbers, so I need >0 and not just =1)

I do not want

```
speed = np.random.randint(0,5) 
L[L > 0] = speed
```

as this changed all the elements >0 to the same random number.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Comment: Create any array of random numbers that is the same shape as `L` and use the same *mask* (`[L>0]`) for the assignment.

Comment: To quote the link you posted, "if your motivation is 'I would like others to explain __ to me', then you are probably OK. " A mask would also not work and I did try this method previously to asking the question.

Comment: Why not `L[L > 0] = np.random.randint(0, 5, size=(L>0).sum())`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will help you.

```
from random import *
L = [0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]

i=0
for n in L:
    x = randint(1, 5)    # Pick a random number between 1 and 5.
    if n > 0:
        L[i] = x
    i+=1
print(L)
```

Comment: Hmm that nearly seems to be working but not quite...It is now giving 2 identical array outputs instead of 1 array

Comment: What about it isn't working? Perhaps I misunderstood what you are trying to do. The above code iterates over an array L containing values of either 0 or 1, and if any value is > 0 it replaces that value with a randomly generated integer between 1 and 5. Is that not what you asked for?

Comment: Yes it is, sorry I solved that second problem so deleted it, but it is still giving 2 lines of array: [1 0 1 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 4 0 0 0 0]
[1 0 1 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 4 0 0 0 0] instead of just [1 0 1 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 4 0 0 0 0]

Comment: check your indentations in your IDE, it sounds like you may have the print statement indented within the for loop.

Comment: Lol, no python indentations can get you sometimes. Glad we got it :)

Comment: If my answer helped you, I would greatly appreciate if you accepted it as the best answer :).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this?

I instantiate `L` with a special pattern, so that it should be easy to discern if the code does what's intended.

```
>>> import random
>>> L = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> list(map(lambda x: random.randint(0,5) if x>0 else x, L))
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 2, 4, 5]
```

I should mention that this code does *not* replace individual elements in `L`. It creates a new list. However, unless the list is especially large this would make no difference, in fact might be slightly faster. (This might be why someone down-voted. You just can't please everyone.)

Comment: Thank you for the help! The previous answer replaced the list as I was requested but I shall keep this comment in case it helps someone else :)